# Texture not showing up when called

Tags: textures, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-development-kit

I'm working on a blueprint that is supposed to, on hit, change the material of an object to a red texture for five seconds and then change it back. The script itself seems to work, but the problem is that the right texture isn't being called. The cylinder, on hit, changes to the default unreal texture, and then back to white in five seconds, so the code is somehow working except for the texture being used. What's strange is that when I mouse over the name of the texture I selected in the node, it shows the correct path. Another object using the same red texture displays it correctly. I even tried pausing the game and looking at the details for the offending object- the details panel says it's TextureRed and shows the preview in there, but in the world it's still just grey checkers.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnFck.jpg

There's a picture of the code, and a screenshot during runtime to show that the texture appears in details but not in the world.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dynamic material instance to change the material at run time.

Here there is a similar question in the Unreal formus:
https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/675903/how-to-change-material-in-runtime.html

If you need some documentation for material istances:
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Rendering/Materials/MaterialInstances/index.html